# Why is the Workflow email not triggering?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I created an approval workflow and based on a status column called 'Workflow Status' in the form I am emailing users. When an item is added, the email is received by the first approve but once he approves and changes the status column to a different value, the second approve is not getting the email.
Below is my form:
 [image]

Below is my 2010 approval workflow:

[image]

The Workflow status has following status values: Requested, Approved by manager and then Approved by Approver2.

Once an item is added, workflow status is set to Requested then email goes to manager with a link to this item, he changes the status to approved by manager and the email then should go to approver 2, which is not working now. Once approver 2 approves the workflow stops and an email is sent from approver 2 to requester and manager. Both manager and approver 2 can reject if needed be which is a chice value available in workflow status column.

Can someone please help me correct the workflow, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First impressions are that you might not have checked the option to run the workflow on item update. It might only be on item creation.

Comment: Good point Jitin, is there any way a workflow could run on both? Item added and updated?

Comment: Yes it can be run on both actions. You need to check both the options.